# Double "foreach" in makepp

Tags: makefile

I am trying to do something similar to nested loops with makepp, and can't figure out how to do it.

Here's basically what I am trying to do.

```
MODULES= A B C
TEMPLATES = X Y Z


#I'd like to make a target which needs both the MODULE and TEMPLATE:

$(MODULE)/$(TEMPLATE) :
  @echo The Module is $(MODULE) and the Template is $(TEMPLATE)


#I've tried foreach, and can do something like:
$(MODULE)/$(foreach) : : foreach $(TEMPLATES)
  @echo The Module is $(MODULE) and the Template is $(foreach)

#Or I can do:
$(foreach)/$(TEMPLATE) : : foreach $(MODULES)
  @echo The Module is $(foreach) and the Template is $(TEMPLATE)
```

How can I create a set of rules that can work for any MODULE/TEMPLATE target?

I'd like the user to be able to have a target like:

```
makepp A/Z
```

not

```
makepp MODULE=A TEMPLATE=Z
```

Then how to make a target which would do the cross-product of all MODULES and TEMPLATES:

```
makepp all
The Module is A and the Template is X
The Module is A and the Template is Y
The Module is A and the Template is Z
... 
The Module is C and the Template is X
The Module is C and the Template is Y
The Module is C and the Template is Z
```

Comment: Is this about `make` (GNU or otherwise) or about `makepp`? Because the tags and the content seem to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

This one is tricky. I am not a makepp expert but if it is sufficiently compatible with GNU make, as it claims to be, the following should do something close from what you want:

```
MODULES     := A B C
TEMPLATES   := X Y Z
ALL         :=

define MODULE_TEMPLATE_rule
$(1)/$(2):
    @echo The Module is $(1) and the Template is $(2)

ALL += $(1)/$(2)
endef

define MODULE_rule
$(foreach template,$(TEMPLATES),$(eval $(call MODULE_TEMPLATE_rule,$(1),$(template))))
endef

$(foreach module,$(MODULES),$(eval $(call MODULE_rule,$(module))))

all: $(ALL)
```

The magic wands, here, are this mixture of `foreach`, `call` and `eval`. The first argument of `call` is a variable name. In my example these variables are defined with the `define-endef` construct but it does not make any difference. `call` expands the variable, assigning its next arguments to the `$(1), $(2)...` *local* variables. So:

```
$(call MODULE_TEMPLATE_rule,A,X)
```

for instance, will return:

```
A/X:
    @echo The Module is A and the Template is X

ALL += A/X
```

But returning is not instantiating. This is where `eval` enters the scene: it expands its argument and the result is parsed as any make statement. The `foreach` is there to iterate over the modules and templates, but you know this already.

Note that the `ALL` variable is progressively built by the iterators over modules and templates. So, if you type `make all` make will build all words in `ALL`, that is, print all combinations:

```
The Module is A and the Template is X
The Module is A and the Template is Y
The Module is A and the Template is Z
The Module is B and the Template is X
The Module is B and the Template is Y
The Module is B and the Template is Z
The Module is C and the Template is X
The Module is C and the Template is Y
The Module is C and the Template is Z
```

That's all. But be warned: in order to use this efficiently you must understand how make works, what it does and in what order. And here, the manual is mandatory.